# Light bulb dash light in VW Golf 2005

Tags: warning-light, tail-lights, bulbs

I have had the bulb indicator light on for a while now but I cannot diagnose it. I am interested to know what the light in the picture is (the rear passenger side light on the inside/boot door)? I cannot get it to light up even after changing the bulb so would like to know what the light does. It may be an electrical fault to that particular one.

PS it is not on - I had my camera flash on

Cheers

[image]

Comment: That looks like a reverse lamp. The red circle surrounding it appears to be a reflector. I think these Golfs had a single reverse lamp on one side and a fog lamp on the other.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is a fog lamp indicator.  Please try this test. Start car, turn on headlamps, low beam, then turn on fog lights.  I believe that light is to make your vehicle more visible during heavy fog conditions.  If not that, its possibly a parking lamp?  (Is there a parking lamp setting on your lamp switch?)

Comment: Turns out it was a reversing light - so the mystery continues about the warning light!